# PKCE OpenId Connect id_token validation via passport

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, pkce

I'm using AppAuth to authenticate users via OpenId Connect but I'm unable to get passport to respond, let along validate the token.

These are the endpoints given at accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration:
authorization_endpoint  "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
token_endpoint  "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"

passport-google-oauth20 defaults to
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

I have an id_token and I've verified it's working at https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?id_token=XYZ gives an empty response.

I've been trying combinations of passport-google-oauth, passport-oauth2, passport-google-oauth, these various google apis(did i mention https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1 etc?), and various headers(JWT, Bearer, etc) and POST params. In every case passport's strategy just silently fails.

I've tried adding some debug info via middleware as described here:
https://dmitryrogozhny.com/blog/easy-way-to-debug-passport-authentication-in-express
It doesn't help.

For the love of god, I've been bashing against this for 48 hours. Someone please help!!!

Comment: (It works when I use passport-google-oauth, if that's ok)

Comment: passport-google-oauth is for oauth, passport-openid is for openid. Similar, but different. I'm more familiar with getting the oauth to work (since I think openid is overkill for "logging in with Google")

Comment: anything would be greatly appreciated. i'll try passport-openid(again). I think what i really just need to know is how passport-whatever expects the request to look. I'm using PKCE so I don't get a redirecturl+parameters, i get a json object from Expo AppAuth.

Comment: Ok, shameless plug: have a look at my [gUsers module](https://github.com/richardeschloss/lightweight-express-server/tree/master/server/modules/google/gUsers) which I use to auth users with Google. It uses passport-google-oauth. I tested that and it works. The passport setup is mainly in the controller code. (I experienced frustration with  passport-oauth2, if I recall correctly)

Comment: ( I got the client ID and secret in [google's dev console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) )

Comment: I looked at passport-openid but I think this is for openid, not openid connect. passport-google-openidconnect uses require('oauth').OAuth2, which I don't think supports PKCE. Similar problem for passport-openidconnect.

Comment: AFAIK, only passport-oauth2 supports PKCE right now, which is what is used by passport-google-oauth2. See Jared Hanson's latest post https://medium.com/passportjs/pkce-support-for-oauth-2-0-e3a77013b278

Comment: I actually emailed Jared directly because I'm so desperate. I really just need some debug info... I've started trying to log things in node_modules/passport-google-oauth2/X but it's not becoming clear yet.

Comment: I do not have a client secret because this is PKCE. If you setup a clientId in google's console for Android or iOS you will not get a secret, that is only for web. I think I can use the web clientid if i use Expo's AuthSession flow instead, but PKCE is suppose to be safer and it should work. I have yet to try the AuthSession route, but might give a try sometime in the next 48 hours if I dont' kill myself first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193071/discussion-between-richs-and-clayton-rabenda).